# How to detect and remove ethernet padding

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am writing the network stack for my os.
While receiving the data from ethernet, I have to detect and remove the padding if data is less than 64 bytes and set the data length, as the standard says.

What is the algorithm for doing this?

If the data contains 'a0' , it is less than 64 bytes and it will be padded. If I am checking bytewise, I will get the second bye 0, so it will also be counted as padded data, however it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Type/Length field will tell you how large the payload is. Wireshark has a pretty good [explanation](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Ethernet):

> Therefore, if the type/length field has a value 1500 or lower, it's a
>   length field, and is followed by an 802.2 header, otherwise it's a
>   type field and is followed by the data for the upper layer protocol
>   (XXX - slight duplicate of sentence above?). Note that when the
>   length/type field is used as a length field the length value specified
>   does **not** include the length of any padding bytes (e.g. if a raw
>   ethernet frame was sent with a payload containing a single byte of
>   data the length field would be set to 0x0001 and 45 padding bytes
>   would be appended to the data field to bring the ethernet frame up to
>   the required minimum 64-byte length).

Comment: Yes thanx, but I am using type field - IP or ARP only. In that case the value will be greater than 1500, but what will be the size of the payload, how will i determine?

Comment: I don't see what you are getting at. If you are using the Type instead of the Length, you just need to check the packet header for IP, or calculate how big the ARP packet is based on the address sizes for the layer-2 and layer-3 protocols which you are using, or determine how to check the length for whatever layer-3 protocol you are using. IP is easy since the IP packet header has a Total Length field. ARP sizes can vary since it can be used on different layer-2 and layer-3 protocols, but calculating the packet size is easy if you know those.